# How to design a web form using MVC pattern

Tags: java, spring-mvc, design-patterns, model-view-controller

I am new to Restful web services in Java and trying to discover it by using MVC design pattern.

I have a simple HTML form with one button and one input text box. When the user types something into the text box, I want to store this data in DB.

This is part of my HTML code:

```
<input type="button" onclick="doneButton()" value="Done" />
```

When the button is clicked, I call "doneButton()" function as

```
<script>
      function doneButton() {

        var param = document.getElementById("text").value;
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
            }
        };
                xhttp.open("GET","MYURL"+param);
        xhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

I am able to call my RestFul web service by the AJAX code above.

In my web service, I call my model class and establish DB connection there. After that, I call my DAO class from my model class and store the required data in DB table.

As far as I know MVC design pattern:

I should not call a web service directly from view. I should first call

- A controller from the view
- This controller should call the Restful web service.
- The web service should call the model class.
- The model class should class DAO and DB operation.

Is this corrent in terms of MVC design pattern?

Can I call a Restful Web service directly from view in MVC design pattern?

I use jersey in web.xml:

RESTful Service
        com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
        1
    
    
        RESTful Service
        /webservices/*

Can you please help me to understand how I should build my application using MVC design pattern?

Thank you for your help.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Let me clarify this for you:

- *View* makes a RESTful call to the *controller*. In other words, your *controller* is one API in your RESTful web service.
- *Controller* calls the DAO layer, which in turn returns data from the underlying database.
- *Controller* uses the returned data, also called the *model*, to return response to the *view*.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an example, hope this helps

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#response_button').on('click', function() {

//              console.log($('#request_textarea').val()); //get your values you need to send to the controller

                $.ajax({
                    type : "GET",
                    url : "url", //call to your controller here.
                    data : "xmlRequest=" + $('#request_textarea').val() + "&functionType=submit_request",    //append your data here 
                    success : function(msg) {
                        $("#response_textarea").text(msg); //response from the controller will be processed here.

                    }
                });

            });
        });
```

Call your DAO layer via the service layer and return the data back to the UI. To answer one of your questions, You can call the controller from the view.

Answer (score 0):

Well thanks for your question.

First I want to tell you that your basic idea is right.

You should not call a web service directly from a view.

Also true is the fact that the controller is your entry point for displaying a view of your application.

But I think there is a little misunderstanding of the term 'view'.

For most MVC Frameworks a view is some sort of a template that is composed of HTML and several placeholders for the data.

A controller might call a REST service. It might also get it's data by querying a database directly. How the data is retrieved is pretty much dependent on the actual implementation of the controller.

Yet, client-side MVC Frameworks like Angular.js are usually designed to work with REST services.

So using REST services for the data operations is a good idea in case you want to use a Javascript MVC Framework.

Now what does a controller do?

A controller listens to a specific resource (a URL) and responds to it.
It does that by binding a (view) model to the requested view (usually an HTML template).

It basically replaces the placeholders from the view-definition with actual data and displays the completed HTML to the client.

If form data gets posted to the controller it parses the data and updates the view model accordingly.

So what is a (view) model and how is it populated with data?

Well, a (view) model is the M in MVC. It is the actual model that is bound to the view. In some cases the view model might be coincident with the domain model. That is usually the case when you are working with javascript based MVC frameworks. So your view model is not just a simple data model that contains the data bound to the placeholders of a specific view template. It terms of js MVC frameworks it might also contain the business logic that is called by the controller...in javascript...on the client. -> That's the downside.

In your case all the DB operations are handled by the REST service. So you have a server side component that has it's own data model which is independent of the MVC structured presentation layer. The REST service is therefore not part of the MVC approach! So you can still implement server side validation in the REST service operations if you want to. But remember that your client side controller has to translate between the client side (view and domain model) and the server side (domain and/or persistence model²).

² nicer word for an anemic domain model.

Roadmap:

1. Find an answer to the question: Do I build my own MVC framework (hint: bad idea!) or do I use an existent MVC framework to take advantage of the MVC approach?
2. Select an MVC framework that fits your needs and download it.
3. Create model, views and controllers.

But before you're actually thinking of building an MVC structured presentation layer you might want to understand what a REST service is and how it is structured and created.

I hope that helps.

Happy coding!